# How to find processid, arguments and name of the job in resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, resque

I'm using resque in my project for background jobs. I want to print the job name and UUID when a job starts. Can anyone tell me how can I find the this information(name of job, UUID, arguments). So that I can use those in before_enqueue hook to print..